# Getting 2019 results from query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have a query that brings the results from three years (2016, 2017 and 2018), and now I need to include a fourth year (2019) and I have no idea how I could do it.

I've tried replicating part of the query changing the year but I got a lot of errors.

```
SELECT MAX(qnt2016) as qnt2016, MAX(qnt2017) as qnt2017, MAX(qnt2018) as qnt2018, empresa FROM
(SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(cliente) IS NULL THEN 0
        ELSE COUNT(cliente) END AS qnt2016,  0 as qnt2017, 0 as qnt2018, empresa, rep
        FROM
        (SELECT E026RAM.CODRAM tipo, E026RAM.DESRAM nome, E085HCL.CODCLI cliente, E085HCL.CODREP rep, E090REP.APEREP empresa
        FROM
        E085HCL, E090REP, E085CLI, E026RAM, E070EMP, E007UFS
        WHERE
        ((E085CLI.SITCLI = 'A')) AND
        ((E026RAM.CODRAM in (1,2,3))) AND
        (((E085CLI.DATCAD >= '2000-01-01') AND (E085CLI.DATCAD <= '2016-12-31'))) AND
        ((E085HCL.CODEMP = 1)) AND
        ((E085CLI.SIGUFS = E007UFS.SIGUFS) AND 
         (E085HCL.CODREP = E090REP.CODREP) AND
        (E085CLI.CODRAM = E026RAM.CODRAM) AND 
        (E085HCL.CODCLI = E085CLI.CODCLI) AND 
        (E085HCL.CODEMP = E070EMP.CODEMP))) C2018
        where tipo not in (10, 15)
        GROUP BY rep, empresa

        union all

        SELECT  0 as qnt2016, CASE WHEN COUNT(cliente) IS NULL THEN 0
                ELSE COUNT(cliente) END AS qnt2017, 0 as qnt2018, empresa, rep
        FROM
        (SELECT E026RAM.CODRAM tipo, E026RAM.DESRAM nome, E085HCL.CODCLI cliente, E085HCL.CODREP rep, E090REP.APEREP empresa
        FROM
      E085HCL, E090REP, E085CLI, E026RAM, E070EMP, E007UFS
        WHERE
        ((E085CLI.SITCLI = 'A')) AND
       ((E026RAM.CODRAM in (1,2,3))) AND
        (((E085CLI.DATCAD >= '2000-01-01') AND (E085CLI.DATCAD <= '2017-12-31'))) AND
        ((E085HCL.CODEMP = 1)) AND
        ((E085CLI.SIGUFS = E007UFS.SIGUFS) AND 
         (E085HCL.CODREP = E090REP.CODREP) AND
        (E085CLI.CODRAM = E026RAM.CODRAM) AND 
        (E085HCL.CODCLI = E085CLI.CODCLI) AND 
        (E085HCL.CODEMP = E070EMP.CODEMP))) C2018
        where tipo not in (10, 15)
        GROUP BY rep, empresa

        union all

        SELECT 0 as qnt2016, 0 as qnt2017, CASE WHEN COUNT(cliente) IS NULL THEN 0
                ELSE COUNT(cliente) END AS qnt2018, empresa, rep
        FROM
        (SELECT
        E026RAM.CODRAM tipo, E026RAM.DESRAM nome, E085HCL.CODCLI cliente, E085HCL.CODREP rep, E090REP.APEREP empresa
        FROM
       E085HCL, E090REP, E085CLI, E026RAM, E070EMP, E007UFS
        WHERE
        ((E085CLI.SITCLI = 'A')) AND
        ((E026RAM.CODRAM in (1,2,3))) AND
        (((E085CLI.DATCAD >= '2000-01-01') AND (E085CLI.DATCAD <= '2018-12-31'))) AND
        ((E085HCL.CODEMP = 1)) AND
        ((E085CLI.SIGUFS = E007UFS.SIGUFS) AND 
         (E085HCL.CODREP = E090REP.CODREP) AND
        (E085CLI.CODRAM = E026RAM.CODRAM) AND 
        (E085HCL.CODCLI = E085CLI.CODCLI) AND 
        (E085HCL.CODEMP = E070EMP.CODEMP))) C2018
        where tipo not in (10, 15)
        GROUP BY rep, empresa, rep) select2
        GROUP BY empresa, rep
        order by rep"
```

Comment: I would imagine you would add 2019 data the exact same way you did with 2018 data.... Just change the date.

Comment: This query wasn't built by me, it was already online when I entered to the team, and the guy who did it is no longer here

Comment: Then this might be a great time to fix it. Seems like using UNION for each year is not a good way to do this. Seems like doing a pivot (maybe dynamic) would be a lot simpler. Well maybe not simpler but would eliminate the need to constantly change the query to add another years data.

Comment: I will read about it and improve my skills, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add another `UNION ALL` before you close your subquery, and add the new field to all the `SELECT` statements

```
SELECT MAX(qnt2016) as qnt2016, MAX(qnt2017) as qnt2017, MAX(qnt2018) as qnt2018, MAX(qnt2019) as qnt2019, empresa FROM
               (SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(cliente) IS NULL THEN 0
                ELSE COUNT(cliente) END AS qnt2016,  0 as qnt2017, 0 as qnt2018, 0 as qnt2019, empresa, rep
                                FROM
                ...
               union all

                SELECT 0 as qnt2016, 0 as qnt2017, , 0 as qnt2018, CASE WHEN COUNT(cliente) IS NULL THEN 0
                        ELSE COUNT(cliente) END AS qnt2019, empresa, rep
                FROM
                (SELECT
                E026RAM.CODRAM tipo, E026RAM.DESRAM nome, E085HCL.CODCLI cliente, E085HCL.CODREP rep, E090REP.APEREP empresa
                FROM
               E085HCL, E090REP, E085CLI, E026RAM, E070EMP, E007UFS
                WHERE
                ((E085CLI.SITCLI = 'A')) AND
                ((E026RAM.CODRAM in (1,2,3))) AND
                (((E085CLI.DATCAD >= '2000-01-01') AND (E085CLI.DATCAD <= '2019-12-31'))) AND
                ((E085HCL.CODEMP = 1)) AND
                ((E085CLI.SIGUFS = E007UFS.SIGUFS) AND 
                 (E085HCL.CODREP = E090REP.CODREP) AND
                (E085CLI.CODRAM = E026RAM.CODRAM) AND 
                (E085HCL.CODCLI = E085CLI.CODCLI) AND 
                (E085HCL.CODEMP = E070EMP.CODEMP))) C2018
                where tipo not in (10, 15)
                GROUP BY rep, empresa, rep) select2
                GROUP BY empresa, rep
                order by rep
```

I answer on what you need to add to the query the data you need, but as stated in the comments this is an **awful** way to make this query. Read about [pivoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017), I think is the right way to rework this query.